# Drop down using rows selected feature in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Below is the shiny application where there is a DT table

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  splitLayout(
    DTOutput("dtable1"),
    DTOutput("dtable2")
  )
)

js <- function(id){ 
  c(
    "table.on('click', 'tr', function(){",
    sprintf("Shiny.setInputValue('%s', true, {priority: 'event'});", id),
    "});"
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["dtable1"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(iris['Sepal.Length'], callback = JS(js("t1")), selection = 'single')
  })
  


  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

So when the user clicks on any row, the remaining columns details be occur. For example in this case they are Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species.

I know we can add another DT table below and do this. But is there a way to do this same table. I just need the contents of the remaining columns with the respect to the rows selected.

below is the similar way I am looking for . This is just a sample, but this the format i am looking for. Basically a HTML table with remaining values

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by *"the remaining columns details be occur"*?

Comment: i mean these ````Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species.````

Comment: I still don't understand. When the users clicks on any rows, the remaining columns ... what do they do? I don't understand what you're trying to say when you say "occur" in this context.

Comment: right now the table has only 1 column right ````Sepal.Length````. Now when the user clicks on 1st row, the remaining columns of the 1st row other than ````Sepal.Length```` should be shown below in the form of HTML table(like the one in the picture above). So basically similar to ````input$dtable1_rows_selected ```` feature in DT table. Got my point?

Comment: can you help me here please

Comment: Not sure if this is an option for you, but you might want to check [reactable's row expansion feature](https://glin.github.io/reactable/articles/examples.html#row-expansion-toggle-button).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [child tables](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/DT_childTables.html).

```r
library(DT)

NestedData <- function(dat, children){
  stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
  g <- function(d){
    if(is.data.frame(d)){
      purrr::transpose(d)
    }else{
      purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
    }
  }
  subdats <- lapply(children, g)
  oplus <- ifelse(lengths(subdats), "&oplus;", "") 
  cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

Dat <- NestedData(
  data.frame(Sepal.Length = iris$Sepal.Length),
  children = lapply(1:nrow(iris), function(i) iris[i, 2:5])
)

## whether to show row names
rowNames = FALSE
colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)

## the callback
parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
callback <- JS(
  sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
  sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
  "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "for(let i = 0; i < nrows; ++i){",
  "  var $cell = table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$();",
  "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
  "    $cell.css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }else{",
  "    $cell.removeClass('details-control');",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "",
  "// --- make the table header of the nested table --- //",
  "var formatHeader = function(d, childId){",
  "  if(d !== null){",
  "    var html = ", 
  "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
  "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + ", 
  "      '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
  "    for(let key in data[0]){",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead></table>'",
  "    return html;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- row callback to style rows of child tables --- //",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#E6FF99');",
  "    }, function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'papayawhip');",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', '#DDFF75');",
  "    }, function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lemonchiffon');",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- header callback to style header of child tables --- //",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'border-top': '3px solid indigo',", 
  "    'color': 'indigo',",
  "    'background-color': '#fadadd'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- make the datatable --- //",
  "var formatDatatable = function(d, childId){",
  "  var data = d[d.length-1] || d._details;",
  "  var colNames = Object.keys(data[0]);",
  "  var columns = colNames.map(function(x){",
  "    return {data: x.replace(/\\./g, '\\\\\\.'), title: x};",
  "  });",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
  "  if(colNames.indexOf('_details') === -1){",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "      'data': data,",
  "      'columns': columns,",
  "      'autoWidth': true,",
  "      'deferRender': true,",
  "      'info': false,",
  "      'lengthChange': false,",
  "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
  "      'order': [],",
  "      'paging': false,",
  "      'scrollX': false,",
  "      'scrollY': false,",
  "      'searching': false,",
  "      'sortClasses': false,",
  "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "      'columnDefs': [{targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}]",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "      'data': data,",
  "      'columns': columns,",
  "      'autoWidth': true,",
  "      'deferRender': true,",
  "      'info': false,",
  "      'lengthChange': false,",
  "      'ordering': data.length > 1,",
  "      'order': [],",
  "      'paging': false,",
  "      'scrollX': false,",
  "      'scrollY': false,",
  "      'searching': false,",
  "      'sortClasses': false,",
  "      'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "      'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "      'columnDefs': [", 
  "        {targets: -1, visible: false},", 
  "        {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},", 
  "        {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
  "      ]",
  "    }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// --- display the child table on click --- //",
  "// array to store id's of already created child tables",
  "var children = [];", 
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
  "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
  "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
  "      td = $(this),",
  "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
  "      rowIdx = row.index();",
  "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('&oplus;');",
  "  } else {",
  "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
  "    if(children.indexOf(childId) === -1){", 
  "      // this child has not been created yet",
  "      children.push(childId);",
  "      row.child(formatHeader(row.data(), childId)).show();",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "      formatDatatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
  "    }else{",
  "      // this child has already been created",
  "      row.child(true);",
  "      td.html('&CircleMinus;');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});")

datatable(
  Dat, 
  callback = callback, rownames = rowNames, escape = -colIdx-1,
  options = list(
    paging = TRUE,
    searching = FALSE,
    columnDefs = list(
      list(
        visible = FALSE, 
        targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx
      ),
      list(
        orderable = FALSE, 
        className = "details-control", 
        targets = colIdx
      ),
      list(
        className = "dt-center", 
        targets = "_all"
      )
    )
  )
)
```

[image]